# Is there a way to hide the length for a <mat-paginator> so it's "1-10" instead of "1-10 of 100"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular 11 web app using a `<mat-paginator>` like this ...

```
<mat-paginator [length]="11"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]"
</mat-paginator>
```

It displays `Showing 1-10 of 11` ... but there's actually more than 11.  All I know if there's more than 11, for technical reasons I don't have the total.

When you click 'next', it becomes `Showing 11-20 of 21` (because I know there's more than 20).

Is there a way to hide the "of 11" part of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label **1-10 of x** is returned by the method MatPaginatorIntl.getRangeLabel(...)
as we can see here https://github.com/angular/components/blob/7cc42f5d835b7971e9ff73e220b801cf7834d515/src/material/paginator/paginator.html#L31

So we could technically create a class extending MatPaginator and providing a custom MatPaginatorIntl with it's own implementation of getRangeLabel().
Firstly extending the MatPaginatorIntl Internationalization class

```js
export class CustomPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl{
   constructor(){
      super();
   }

   getRangeLabel: (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number){
      return `${page * pageSize + 1} – ${startIndex + pageSize}`;
   }
}
```

Then, you provide your CustomPaginatorIntl at app.module.ts:

```js
providers: [{ provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomPaginatorIntl}]
```